# 6 check boxes, 2 sets of 3, need 1,2 & 3 to be false when 1 is true, similar with 4,5 & 6 but also must work independently

Tags: excel, vba

Very new to Excel Macros and I have managed to do what I want with 6 boxes but they need to work as 2 sets of 3.

The code allows me to only have 1 CheckBox on at once, but I need this to happen separately for boxes 1-3 and 4-6

So Question 1, 3 possible answers, but only 1 can be ticked, then when I move to question 2, only one possible answer again, but the answer cant turn any of the previous answers off and visa versa

Here is the code :-

```
Sub CheckBox1()

Dim cb As CheckBox

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If cb.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Name Then
        cb.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 2").Value = True
End If

Next

End Sub
Sub CheckBox2()

Dim cb As CheckBox

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If cb.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 2").Name Then
        cb.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 3").Value = True
End If

Next

End Sub
Sub CheckBox3()

Dim cb As CheckBox

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If cb.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 3").Name Then
        cb.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = True
End If

Next

End Sub
Sub CheckBox4()

Dim cb As CheckBox

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If cb.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 4").Name Then
        cb.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 5").Value = True
End If

Next

End Sub
Sub CheckBox5()

Dim cb As CheckBox

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If cb.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 5").Name Then
        cb.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 6").Value = True
End If

Next

End Sub
Sub CheckBox6()

Dim cb As CheckBox

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If cb.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 6").Name Then
        cb.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 4").Value = True
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't actually want checkboxes.  You want optionbuttons.  you can give them a group and then only one optionbutton per group can be selected.

Comment: Cant seem to find a way to have the button show a tick when selected? Can this be done?

Comment: ? It's an optionbutton (also called a radio button), it displays as a circle.  Is a "tick" somehow different?

Comment: Ok I found the circle button but once any of the tick boxes are selected they need to link to another box to provide an output. The linked box with True & False answers were =IF(S14, 18,0), how does this now work

Comment: Learn about optionbuttons: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-buttons.html